# Different buffer length in gdb

Tags: c, gdb, buffer, overflow

I am trying to exploit the following program :

```
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char little_array[512];
    if (argc > 1)
        strcpy(little_array, argv[1]);
}
```

I want to first find the buffer length in order to overflow the stack so I use

```
(gdb) x/20xw $esp-532
0xffffcda8:     0x00000001      0x00000000      0x41414141      0x41414141
0xffffcdb8:     0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0xffffcdc8:     0x00000041      0xf7fe6b8c      0xf7ffd000      0x00000000
0xffffcdd8:     0xffffce98      0xf7fe70db      0xf7ffdaf0      0xf7fd8e08
0xffffcde8:     0x00000001      0x00000001      0x00000000      0xf7ff55ac
(gdb)
```

And I find the address (since I ran 'AAAA'), so the address is 0xffffcdaa .
**Im running a 64bit system, disabled ASLR.** 
And I defined the buffer 512 bytes long.

And I get

```
(gdb) p 0xffffddf0 - 0xffffcdaa
$1 = 4166
(gdb)
```

How can this be? It has something to do with my 64bit system? Im trying to follow an old book and cant really find anything better.

I used this program to find the starting point

```
// find_start.c
unsigned long find_start(void)
{
    __asm__("movl %esp, %eax");
}
int main()
{
    printf("0x%x\n",find_start());
}
```

(when this program compiled with the -m32 flag the output of it gives me a starting point that gives me a little better result, 574, but still is too far)

Comment: I want to add that I compiled the program using the -m32 bit option in gcc. Is it possible that I cant overflow the buffer because of the system I am running?

Comment: Where did you get the `0xffffddf0` from?

Comment: That program I posted called find_start.c 
UPDATE : I just ran with a similar problem on a old debian 3.1 (sarge) . 
So Im guessing im doing something wrong here.

Comment: can you tell us all the arguments passed to gcc when compiling the program that you're trying to exploit?

Comment: `-fno-stack-protector -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -m32 ` under 64bit linux mint. But still, same thing happens in Debian Sarge (without those options since they didnt exist)